# Dispatcher.Invoke doesn't change value of Label

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dispatcher

In the thread I want to change value of Label

I found out that I have to use Dispatcher.Invoke.

Tried this code:

```
Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Function() Me.Label2.Content = "Scanning done."))
```

but it doesn't change the value.

What am I doing wrong?

@edit: my target framework is 4.0

Comment: How long are you waiting. BackgroundPriority will not be immediate change...

Comment: I waited about 10 sec, but I tried changing background to other priorities. Still nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most glaring issues are you're using a `Function` where you should be using a `Sub` since there is no return value.  Also, your parameters are backward.

The following should work for you:

```
Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub() Me.Label2.Content = "Scanning done.", DispatcherPriority.Background)
```

Comment: but this:  `Label2.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Function() Label2.Content = "Scanning done."))` doesn't work either

Comment: The parameters were in correct order, but Sub() fixed my problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this (.net 4.5, in c#):

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Label2.Content = "Scanning done.");
```

Comment: They're asking for the syntax in VB.NET.  I updated the tags in the question accordingly.